# Double integral of Dirac delta

Tags: definite-integrals, dirac-delta

Is this integral possible? Everything is positive and real. Maybe a substitution of variables?

$$\frac{1}{\Delta t\ \Delta \varepsilon} \int_t^{t+\Delta t} \int_{\varepsilon-\Delta \varepsilon/2}^{\varepsilon+\Delta \varepsilon/2} \delta\left(E - \frac{1}{2 m} \left( \frac{q V \tau}{d} \right)^2 \right) \mathrm{d}E\ \mathrm{d}\tau$$

Comment: Why is $\epsilon$ both the dummy variable of integration and appearing at the upper lower limits?

Comment: Different variable. I'll change it for clarity.

Comment: I think it's zero if $(t,t+\Delta t) \cap (\frac{d}{qV}\sqrt{2m(\epsilon-\Delta\epsilon/2)},\frac{d}{qV}\sqrt{2m(\epsilon+\Delta\epsilon/2)}) = \emptyset$. Otherwise it's one. Not sure.

Comment: it is of the form $C \int_a^b \int_c^d \delta(y-k x^2) dy dx$, can you compute that one ?

Answer (score 0):

Perform first the $E$-integral, which is by definition equal to $1$ if 
$$
\epsilon-\Delta\epsilon/2<\frac{1}{2m}\left(\frac{qV\tau}{d}\right)^2<\epsilon+\Delta\epsilon/2
$$
and zero otherwise. Solving the inequality for $\tau>0$ (assuming $\epsilon-\Delta\epsilon/2$>0)
$$
\sqrt{(\epsilon-\Delta\epsilon/2)2md^2/q^2V^2}<\tau<\sqrt{(\epsilon+\Delta\epsilon/2)2md^2/q^2V^2}\ .
$$
Then you just need to compare $
\sqrt{(\epsilon\pm\Delta\epsilon/2)2md^2/q^2V^2}$ with $t,t+\Delta t$. According to different values of the parameters, you will have to solve different integrals, for example
$$
\int_{
\sqrt{(\epsilon-\Delta\epsilon/2)2md^2/q^2V^2}}^{
\sqrt{(\epsilon+\Delta\epsilon/2)2md^2/q^2V^2}}d\tau\ ,
$$
or 
$$
\int_{t}^{t+\Delta t}d\tau\ ,
$$
or others. The $\tau$-integral to be performed is $\int_\sigma d\tau$, where $$\sigma=[
\sqrt{(\epsilon-\Delta\epsilon/2)2md^2/q^2V^2},
\sqrt{(\epsilon+\Delta\epsilon/2)2md^2/q^2V^2}]\cap [t,t+\Delta t]\ ,$$ so the support $\sigma$ may change in different regions of parameter space.

Comment: Reasons for downvoting?